# Allowing for an attribute of a class to be optional (Basic OOP Java)

Tags: java, oop

I have a DVD class which has the instance variables title, artist & genre.

I want to be able to create a DVD object with all three **OR** just with the title and artist values.

Code So Far:

```
class DVD {

    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String artist;

    public String getTitle () {
        return title;
    }

    public String getGenre () {
        return genre;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public void playIt() {
        System.out.println("Playing the song");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Title: "+ title + "\n"
              + "Genre: "+ genre + "\n"
              + "Artist: "+ artist;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }


}
```

Main Method:

```
class TestDVDs {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        DVD film = new DVD();
        film.setTitle("Some Film");
        film.setGenre("Horror");
        film.setArtist("Someone");
        film.print();
    }
}
```

if I simply leave out the line where I set the genre it is displayed as Genre: null which is undesireable

I know this is a basic question but I am really stuck here.

Comment: There is this nifty operation known as `if`.

Comment: Your `genre` attribute is already optional, as evidenced by the fact that you can leave it `null`. I think what you are asking is how to print out the info about the song in a more readable way. If this is the case, consider rewriting your question (especially the title).

Comment: What is the need to have `setXxX()` methods? Why not use two different constructors`, one which will take two parameters `DVD(String title, String artist) {this(title, artist, "");}` and another constructor, which will take three parameters `DVD(String title, String artist, String genre){this.artist = artist;this.title = title; this.genre = genre;}` call the appropriate, as per the input one has, at runtime.

Comment: Use an if statement? if (genre != null) {..}

Answer (score 2):

The code to change that `genre` field can contain `null`

```
public String toString() {
    return "Title: "+ title + "\n"
          + "Genre: "+ (genre==null?"":genre) + "\n"
          + "Artist: "+ artist;
}
```

Comment: I can see it is achievable with an if, but is this best practice? I thought there was some specific OOP trick to this.?

Comment: the trick is to prevent null pointer exception in the method that doesn't throw it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to handle it depends on what you want to achieve. If you want it to be `Null` unless set and only modify the toString result depending on the value of `genre`, you can build different strings in `toString`, for example:

```
public String toString() {
    String res = "Title: "+ title + "\n";
    if ( genre != null)
    {
        res += "Genre: " + genre + "\n";
    }
}
```

If you want it to be an empty string by default, you can set it so:

```
private String genre = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class DVD {
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String genre;
    public DVD() {
        title = "";
        artist = "";
        genre = "";
    }
    // Rest of your code.
}
```

Setting a constructor like this will set all the default values to whatever you place in the quotes just by calling new DVD();

Another way you could set default values is by setting them in the variable declaration.

```
class DVD {
    private String title = "";
    private String artist = "";
    private String genre = "";
    // Rest of your code.
}
```

Assuming I read your post correctly you just don't want it to display null when you ask for the genre (or whatever). This code will simply display an empty string instead.

Now if you don't want the variable even displayed in your printout if it's null then:

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    if (title != null) result = result + "Title: " + title + "\n";
    if (genre != null) result = result + "Genre: " + genre + "\n";
    if (artist != null) result = result + "Artist: " + artist + "\n";
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)).  Specifically:

```
class DvdFactory {
    public static DVD newDvd(String artist, String title){...}
    public static DVD newDvd(String artist, String title, String genre{...}
}

class Dvd {
    private String artist, title;
    public Dvd(String artist, String title){...}
}

class DvdWithGenre extends Dvd {
    private String genre;
    public DvdWithGenre(String artist, String title, String genre){
        super(artist, title);
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

This is the OO approach to the problem you've described. To get a new DVD, you call DvdFactory.newDvd(...).

Since this is a very simple use-case, I think you probably want the factory methods to be class methods (static) rather than object methods.  Note that more complex factories that need to pass a common reference to their products or those that need to be used during automated testing may work better as objects.